# Service to receive UDP packet

Tags: android, android-service

I've created a service in order to listen if I receive message from a server (PC). But it doesn't work and I don't know why. Someone can help me ?

I call my service in my main activity , in the increate() like this :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, UDPlisten.class);
  startService(intent);
```

I don't know how I can retrieve the data sent by the PC in my main activity. Because I would like receive a notification when the server send a message to the app.

Service :

```
public class UDPlisten extends Service {

static String UDP_BROADCAST = "UDPBroadcast";
DatagramSocket socket;


private void listenAndWaitAndThrowIntent(int port) throws Exception {
    byte[] recvBuf = new byte[15000];
    if (socket == null || socket.isClosed()){
        socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
        socket.setBroadcast(true);
    }
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
    Log.e("UDP", "Waiting for UDP broadcast");
    socket.receive(packet);
    String message = new String(packet.getData()).trim();
    Log.e("UDP", "message: " + message);

//  broadcastIntent(senderIP, message);
    //socket.close();
}
private void broadcastIntent(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(UDPlisten.UDP_BROADCAST);
    intent.putExtra("message", message);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
     Thread UDPBroadcastThread;

void startListenForUDPBroadcast() {
    UDPBroadcastThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
               // InetAddress broadcastIP =InetAddress.getByName("10.0.2.16"); 
                int port = 4000;
                while (shouldRestartSocketListen) {
                    listenAndWaitAndThrowIntent(port);
                }
                //if (!shouldListenForUDPBroadcast) throw new ThreadDeath();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("UDP", "no longer listening for UDP broadcasts cause of error " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    UDPBroadcastThread.start();
}
           private Boolean shouldRestartSocketListen=true;

void stopListen() {
    shouldRestartSocketListen = false;
    socket.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    shouldRestartSocketListen = true;
    startListenForUDPBroadcast();
    Log.i("UDP", "Service started");
};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopListen();
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    shouldRestartSocketListen = true;
    startListenForUDPBroadcast();
    Log.i("UDP", "Service started");
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you declared your service inside the manifest file?

Comment: yes, like this : <service android:name=".UDPlisten" ></service>

Comment: Can you provide logcat output? And now the problem you have is that you don't receive a message, or something more than that?

Comment: I have no errors in the log cat .. 
Yes the problem is I don't receive anything and I want transfer the data received from the service to the main activity.

Comment: Are you getting the log messages your code should generate?  Are your device and your PC on a common wifi network?  If not, then this probably shouldn't work.

Comment: No I don't receive any log messages. And yes, my PC and my device are on a the same wifi network.

Comment: Nobody can resolve my problem ?